# React.js Appropiate structure of a multiple language app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**: I'm using Django as the framework for the backend, here, I have a single app with multiple models (one per each language) and React.js as the framework for the fronted. Once the main version is over, I want to make the site multilanguage.

**Question**: Should I duplicate the original app (say this app is in English) deploy these two versions or maybe create these versions inside of the main version?

***Directory structure case A***

```
mainAPP-EN
mainAPP-ES
```

***Directory structure case B***

```
mainAPP
  -> EN
  -> ES
```

Note. The site is not complex so both options are suitable for me.
Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: try to use some lib and avoid duplicate code. [see here some example](https://medium.com/@ricklee_10931/react-multi-lingual-with-react-i18next-57879f986168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple modules to do that. In fact I would strongly suggest you do not do that, it will become very hard to maintain (IE: bugs and features need to be fixed on each language).

Django's support for multiple locales is great ([official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/)):

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

On the React side, there are many libraries, the one I like for its simplicity is [Airbnb's Polyglot](https://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/):

```js
const SPANISH_PHRASES = {
  locale: 'es',

  phrases: {
    "hello": "hola"
  },
};

const polyglot = new Polyglot(SPANISH_PHRASES);

polyglot.t("hello"); // returns "hola"
```

Usually, you would like to define a, say, `Translate` component that does this under the hood:

```js
// basic example, needs more elaboration!
export default function Translate({ phrase }) {
  return <span>{ polyglot.t(phrase) }</span>
}
```

Then to use it:

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
   <SomeMenu><Translate phrase="hello" /></SomeMenu>
  );
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you defined `locale='es'`, can I define more languages in the same var or should I create a new polyglot, say polyglotES and polyglotFR?

Comment: You would need to overwrite the Polyglot object indeed with a new one, for example: `let polyglot = new Polyglot(PHRASES_FR)`. The `locale` mostly needs to be set for pluralizations to work correctly (for example, Russian has multiple ways to do plurals, Chinese has no plurals, etc).

Comment: on Django side, can we use Rosetta or something simillar to have nice UI for text translation?